# Lining up free translation in interlinear glossing with expex

Tags: linguistics, expex

I'm trying to line up the English translation using the `expex` package. `expex` allows you to create a side panel of the free translation. What I would like is a way to define a fixed with to this side panel.

I am currently doing the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% extra packages
\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[nomain]{glossaries}
\usepackage{leipzig}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{expex}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

% dimensions
\newlength{\defparindent}
\setlength{\defparindent}{\parindent}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

% custom ling styles
\definelingstyle{Conversation}{aboveexskip=0pt,belowexskip=0pt,
  belowglpreambleskip=0pt,aboveglftskip=0pt,glwordalign=left,
  everyglpreamble=\bf,glftpos=right,glhangstyle=none}
\definelingstyle{ConversationDescription}{aboveexskip=4pt,
  glwordalign=left,glhangindent=0em,glftpos=right,
  glhangstyle=none,everyglpreamble=\setlength{\parskip}{6pt}}
\definelingstyle{ConversationTitle}{aboveexskip=4pt,
  glwordalign=left,glhangindent=0em,belowglpreambleskip=0pt,
  aboveglftskip=0pt,glftpos=right,glhangstyle=none}

\pagestyle{empty}

\newleipzig{abil}{abil}{abilitative}        % abilitative -(y)Abil
\newleipzig{aff}{aff}{affirmative}          % affirmative
\newleipzig{aor}{aor}{aorist}               % aorist
\newleipzig{buf}{buf}{buffer}               % buffer
\newleipzig{defn}{def}{definite past}       % definite past
\newleipzig{der}{der}{derivative}           % derivative
\newleipzig{ppo}{ppo}{primarypost}          % primary postposition

\setdefaultlanguage{turkish}

\begin{document}

\columnratio{0.31,0.69}
\begin{paracol}{2}
(22.1) \textbf{CONVERSATION:}

\switchcolumn
\exdisplay[lingstyle=ConversationTitle]
\begingl
\glpreamble \textbf{Bir kitap ariyorum.}//
\gla \textbf{Bir} \textbf{kitap}
\textbf{arı}$^{(I)}$\textbf{-yor-um.}//
\glb \textbf{A} \textbf{book}
\textbf{to.look.for}-\Prog{}-\Fsg{}.//
\glft I am looking for a book.//
\endgl
\xe
\end{paracol}

\exdisplay[lingstyle=ConversationDescription]
\begingl
\glpreamble \textit{Cemal kitapçıda bayramlarla ilgili birkitap
arıyor.}//
\gla \textit{Cemal}
$\underbrace{\textit{kitap-çı}}_\textrm{kitapçı}$\textit{-da}
\textit{bayram-lar-la} \textit{ilgili}$^{(lA)}$ \textit{bir}
\textit{kitap} \textit{arı}$^{(I)}$\textit{-yor}.//
\glb Cemal $\underbrace{book-\Der{}}_\textrm{bookseller}$-\Loc{}
festival-\Pl{}-\Ppo{} about a book to.look.for-\Prog{}.\Tsg{}.//
\glft Cemal is looking for a book about festivals at the bookseller.
//

\endgl
\xe

\medskip

\columnratio{0.15,0.85}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\hfill Satıcı:

\switchcolumn
\exdisplay[lingstyle=Conversation]
\begingl
\glpreamble Buyrun efendim, size nasıl yardımcı olabilirim? //
\gla Buyur$^{(-/I/A)}$-un efend-im, siz-e nasıl yardım-cı
ol$^{(-)}$-abil-ir-im? //
\glb to.order-\Imp{}.\Ssg{} lord-\Poss{}.\Fsg{}, you-\Dat{} how
help-\Der{} to.be-\Abil{}-\Aor{}-\Poss{}.\Fsg{}? //
\glft Welcome, sir. How may I help you? //
\endgl
\xe

\switchcolumn*
\hfill Cemal:

\switchcolumn
\exdisplay[lingstyle=Conversation]
\begingl
\glpreamble Bir kitap arıyorum, ama adını hatırlamıyorum. //
\gla Bir kitap arı$^{(I)}$-yor-um, ama ad-ı-n-ı
hatırla$^{(I)}$-m-ıyor-um. //
\glb A book to.look.for-\Prog{}-\Fsg{}, but
name-\Poss{}-\Buf-\Acc{}.\Tsg{} to.remember-\Neg{}-\Prog{}-\Fsg{}.//
\glft I'm looking for a book but I don't remember its title. //
\endgl
\xe

\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

I am using the `paracol` package to align the conversation text towards the bottom. The left column is for the parties in the conversation and the second column is the interlinear glossed text. I am doing something similar for the interlinear gloss in the CONVERSATION title.

While there is a `\glwidth` parameter to set the total width of the glosses, there doesn't seem to be something for the right-hand side panel.

I thought about posting to the [ling-tex](http://heim.ifi.uio.no/~dag/ling-tex.html) list but the [web page](http://ifi-lists.uio.no/mailman/listinfo/ling-tex@ifi.uio.no/) to be added to this list appears to be down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want the free translation panels of each style to be left-aligned with each other. As far as I can tell from the `expex` documentation, you can't specify a fixed width for the free translation panel, but you can use the parameter `ssratio` to specify the width of the left panel relative to the overall gloss width. Its default value is `0.6`.

I modified your MWE, keeping the default width of the ConversationTitle style and changing `ssratio` in the other styles so that the free translation panels are left-aligned with respect to each other. You would have to adjust these values to get the desired width.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% extra packages
\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[nomain]{glossaries}
\usepackage{leipzig}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{expex}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

% dimensions
\newlength{\defparindent}
\setlength{\defparindent}{\parindent}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

% custom ling styles
\definelingstyle{Conversation}{aboveexskip=0pt,belowexskip=0pt,
  belowglpreambleskip=0pt,aboveglftskip=0pt,glwordalign=left,
  everyglpreamble=\bf,glftpos=right,glhangstyle=none,
  glrightskip=0pt plus .3\hsize,                             % added to avoid overfull glosses
  ssratio=.6795}                            % width of the left panel is 67.95% of the glwidth
\definelingstyle{ConversationDescription}{aboveexskip=4pt,
  glwordalign=left,glhangindent=0em,glftpos=right,
  glhangstyle=none,everyglpreamble=\setlength{\parskip}{6pt},
  glrightskip=0pt plus .3\hsize,                             % added to avoid overfull glosses
  ssratio=.7363}                            % width of the left panel is 73.63% of the glwidth
\definelingstyle{ConversationTitle}{aboveexskip=4pt,
  glwordalign=left,glhangindent=0em,belowglpreambleskip=0pt,
  aboveglftskip=0pt,glftpos=right,glhangstyle=none,
  glrightskip=0pt plus .3\hsize}                             % added to avoid overfull glosses

\pagestyle{empty}

\newleipzig{abil}{abil}{abilitative}        % abilitative -(y)Abil
\newleipzig{aff}{aff}{affirmative}          % affirmative
\newleipzig{aor}{aor}{aorist}               % aorist
\newleipzig{buf}{buf}{buffer}               % buffer
\newleipzig{defn}{def}{definite past}       % definite past
\newleipzig{der}{der}{derivative}           % derivative
\newleipzig{ppo}{ppo}{primarypost}          % primary postposition

\setdefaultlanguage{turkish}

\begin{document}

\columnratio{0.31,0.69}
\begin{paracol}{2}
(22.1) \textbf{CONVERSATION:}

\switchcolumn
\exdisplay[lingstyle=ConversationTitle]
\begingl
\glpreamble \textbf{Bir kitap ariyorum.}//
\gla \textbf{Bir} \textbf{kitap}
\textbf{arı}$^{(I)}$\textbf{-yor-um.}//
\glb \textbf{A} \textbf{book}
\textbf{to.look.for}-\Prog{}-\Fsg{}.//
\glft I am looking for a book.//
\endgl
\xe
\end{paracol}

\exdisplay[lingstyle=ConversationDescription]
\begingl
\glpreamble \textit{Cemal kitapçıda bayramlarla ilgili birkitap
arıyor.}//
\gla \textit{Cemal}
$\underbrace{\textit{kitap-çı}}_\textrm{kitapçı}$\textit{-da}
\textit{bayram-lar-la} \textit{ilgili}$^{(lA)}$ \textit{bir}
\textit{kitap} \textit{arı}$^{(I)}$\textit{-yor}. //
\glb Cemal $\underbrace{book-\Der{}}_\textrm{bookseller}$-\Loc{}
festival-\Pl{}-\Ppo{} about a book to.look.for-\Prog{}.\Tsg{}.//
\glft Cemal is looking for a book about festivals at the bookseller. //

\endgl
\xe

\medskip

\columnratio{0.15,0.85}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\hfill Satıcı:

\switchcolumn
\exdisplay[lingstyle=Conversation]
\begingl
\glpreamble Buyrun efendim, size nasıl yardımcı olabilirim? //
\gla Buyur$^{(-/I/A)}$-un efend-im, siz-e nasıl yardım-cı
ol$^{(-)}$-abil-ir-im? //
\glb to.order-\Imp{}.\Ssg{} lord-\Poss{}.\Fsg{}, you-\Dat{} how
help-\Der{} to.be-\Abil{}-\Aor{}-\Poss{}.\Fsg{}? //
\glft Welcome, sir. How may I help you? //
\endgl
\xe

\switchcolumn*
\hfill Cemal:

\switchcolumn
\exdisplay[lingstyle=Conversation]
\begingl
\glpreamble Bir kitap arıyorum, ama adını hatırlamıyorum. //
\gla Bir kitap arı$^{(I)}$-yor-um, ama ad-ı-n-ı
hatırla$^{(I)}$-m-ıyor-um. //
\glb A book to.look.for-\Prog{}-\Fsg{}, but
name-\Poss{}-\Buf-\Acc{}.\Tsg{} to.remember-\Neg{}-\Prog{}-\Fsg{}.//
\glft I'm looking for a book but I don't remember its title. //
\endgl
\xe

\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```